# Retrieving XML runs for 5 hours

Tags: android, xml, performance, xml-parsing

I receive 360K of data from a server which I transform into a XML file on my phone. The final file is about 1.3 Mb. Later, I try to read this file and on my GT-S5660 and this process runs for 5(!) hours. Although it produces a correct result I wonder if there is a way to optimize this process. I have an iphone version of it, and there the process completes in less than 5 seconds. 
**Is this a normal behaviour? If so, would SQLIte be an alternative?**
Here's my code:

```
FileInputStream fileos;
    try {
        fileos = openFileInput("TarifsCache" + Constants.VERSION + ".txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return;
    }
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db;
    try {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        return;
    }
    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = db.parse(new InputSource(fileos));
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    for (int i = 0;; i++) {

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Cache" + i);

        Node node = nodeList.item(0);
        if (node == null)
            break;
        Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

        NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("area_ref");
        Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
        nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
        tarifread.area_ref = Integer.parseInt(((Node) nameList.item(0))
                .getNodeValue());
```

followed by plenty of other element retrievals.

Comment: You should profile your code and see which part takes the longest. See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: I did that. The db.parse(...) alone runs for 5 minutes. normalize takes 25 seconds, the first doc.getElementsByTagName("Cache" + i) takes 1 minute, aso. There is no single command line causing the problem

Comment: Nobody în this forum who can help?

Comment: Maybe you could post an excerpt of your input and output XML file. It looks like you've already posted the relevant _parsing_ sections. Right off the bat, I see that you're using `DOM` instead of `SAX` (which is more efficient) but I wouldn't be able to say for sure without seeing exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for this input. Will try with SAX and report here in a few days if this fixed the problem

Comment: SAX fixed the problem. Runtime went down from 5 hours to 5 seconds...! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use advance parser parser like SAX and dnt use STAX as its not support in android .